# C++: cannot call member function without object

Tags: c++, templates, static

I have a class nammed MessageQueue, with 2 methods (one template, and one normal) with a different signature, but with the same name. All the methods are **static**.

In my class MessageQueue (MessageQueue.h):

```
template <class T> void MessageQueue::sendMessage(const ___handle queue,
                                              const MESSAGE_ACTION &action,
                                              const T *pMessage)
{
    sendMessage(queue, action, (void*)pMessage, sizeof(pMessage));
}
```

In MessageQueue.cpp:

```
void MessageQueue::sendMessage(const ___handle queue, const MESSAGE_ACTION &action,
                           const void *pMessage, const ___uint16 &size)
{
  // ...
}
```

I have a compilation error on this line:

```
sendMessage(queue, action, (void*)pMessage, sizeof(pMessage));
```

The error is:

> error: cannot call member function 'void MessageQueue::sendMessage(void*, const MESSAGE_ACTION&, const void*, const ___uint16&)' without object

Comment: Where is that line? Most probably you'll have to specify scope. MessageQueue::sendMessage(...)

Comment: `sizeof(pMessage)` will always be 4 or 8, depending on your system. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @tgmath: `static` is written next to the member functions in the class definition, not in the function definitions. But I'd bet that there is one `static` missing.

Comment: I found my error: I didn't define the method sendMessage with static type like that: 

**static** void sendMessage(const ___handle queue, const MESSAGE_ACTION &action, const void *pMessage, const ___uint16 &size);

Comment: Oh, I see, it's the line in MessageQueue.h.

Answer (score 0):

The call of `sendMessage` seems to be static access, but the method is not declated static. Either the medthod should be declared static or an instance of ``MessageQueue is needed; see [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/) for an explanation of static member functions.